# Scala: different foldRight implementations in list

Tags: scala

I've just figured out that scala (I'm on 2.12) provides completely different implementations of **foldRight** for **immutable list** and **mutable list**.

Immutable list (List.scala):

```
override def foldRight[B](z: B)(op: (A, B) => B): B =
    reverse.foldLeft(z)((right, left) => op(left, right))
```

Mutable list (LinearSeqOptimized.scala):

```
  def foldRight[B](z: B)(@deprecatedName('f) op: (A, B) => B): B =
    if (this.isEmpty) z
    else op(head, tail.foldRight(z)(op))
```

Now I'm just curious.
Could you please explain me why was it implemented so differently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `override` in `List` seems to override the `foldRight` in `LinearSeqOptimized`. The implementation in `LinearSeqOptimized`

```
def foldRight[B](z: B)(@deprecatedName('f) op: (A, B) => B): B =
  if (this.isEmpty) z
  else op(head, tail.foldRight(z)(op))
```

looks exactly like the canonical definition of `foldRight` as a catamorphism from your average theory book. However, as was noticed in [SI-2818](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2818), this implementation is not stack-safe (throws unexpected `StackOverflowError` for long lists). Therefore, it was replaced by a stack-safe `reverse.foldLeft` in [this commit](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/6db4db93a7d976f1a3b99f8f1bffff23a1ae3924). The `foldLeft` is stack-safe, because it has been implemented by a while loop:

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(@deprecatedName('f) op: (B, A) => B): B = {
  var acc = z
  var these = this
  while (!these.isEmpty) {
    acc = op(acc, these.head)
    these = these.tail
  }
  acc
}
```

That hopefully explains why it was overridden in `List`. It doesn't explain why it was not overridden in other classes. I guess it's simply because the mutable data structures are used less often and quite differently anyway (often as buffers and accumulators during the construction of immutable ones).

Hint: there is a `blame` button in the top right corner over every file on Github, so you can always track down what was changed when, by whom, and why.

Comment: That was helpful! Thanks!

Comment: @Normal I think, in the long run, the hint with `git blame` is more useful than the answer itself. And thanks for the question, I've never paid any attention to the `@deprecatedName` annotation before :]

Comment: I'm totally agree) Thanks for that hint.