# appending elements to list of list in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

i have created a empty scala mutable list

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
val list_of_list : List[List[String]] = List.empty
```

i want to append elements to it as below

```
filtered_df.collect.map(
          r => {

            val val_list = List(r(0).toString,r(4).toString,r(5).toString)
            list_of_list += val_list
          }
        )
```

error that i am getting is

```
Error:(113, 26) value += is not a member of List[List[String]]
  Expression does not convert to assignment because receiver is not assignable.
            list_of_list += val_list
```

Can someone help

Comment: You have to change that `val list_of_list` to `var list_of_list` and also change the type of `list_of_list` into a mutable alternative

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration seems wrong:

```
val list_of_list : List[List[String]] = List.empty
```

means that you've declared `scala.collection.immutable.List` whose operations return a new list without changing the current.

To fix the error you need to change the outer `List` type to `ListBuffer` that you imported above the declaration as follows:

```
val list_of_list : ListBuffer[List[String]] = ListBuffer.empty
```

---

Also it looks like you don't to use `map` here unless you want to modify your data collected from `DataFrame`, so you can change it to `foreach`:

```
filtered_df.collect.foreach {
  r => {
    val val_list = List(r(0).toString,r(4).toString,r(5).toString)
    list_of_list += val_list
  }
}
```

---

Furthermore you can make it in a functional way without resorting to `ListBuffer`, by using immutable `List` and `foldRight` as follows:

```
val list_of_list: List[List[String]] = 
  filtered_df.collect.toList
    .foldRight(List.empty[List[String]])((r, acc) => List(r(0).toString,r(4).toString,r(5).toString) :: acc)
```

`toList` is used to achieve a stack safety when calling `foldRight`, [because it's not stack safe for `Arrays`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49203340/9128490)

[More info about `foldLeft` and `foldRight`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40827710/scala-fold-right-and-fold-left)

Comment: Unfortunately `foldRight` is not stack-safe I would prefer `foldLeft` instead `foldRight`, `foldLeft` is stack safe

Comment: @BorisAzanov you're right. It's stack-safe only for immutable `List`. Edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to change that `val list_of_list` to `var list_of_list`. That alone would not be enough as you also have to change the type of `list_of_list` into a `mutable` alternative.